# Double slit experiment on electrons

Tags: experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

Consider a constant flux of electrons through the double slit but let the upper part of the slit be free of any material for a secondary flux of a less frequent electrons passing above the slit.As the second flux does not pass through the double slit but instead slightly above it, it should not present any interference but only a clump pattern.Can it be influenced by the first flux so showing interference pattern on the screen too, so instead of a hybrid clump and interference pattern we see only the interference pattern?

Comment: Are you asking about a single coherent source that simultaneously illuminates all of the "slits?" Or are you asking about two distinct sources (frequent vs. less frequent.) If it's the latter, each source will create its own interference pattern, and what you see on the screen simply will be the sum of two patterns.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Will the secondary flux show a clump pattern so the sum is a hybride with an interference and clump part?

Comment: Each distinct coherent source will create its own interference pattern. In the classic double slit experiment, it's a pattern of regularly spaced vertical bands of dark and light. If a single source illuminates more apertures besides the usual two, then the pattern will become more complicated. I am not qualified to to predict what that might look like. If you have two or more distinct sources though, then the pattern cast by any one source will _not_ interfere with patterns cast by any of the others. The patterns cast by different sources will simply add together.